How to cross-compile GDAL for aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu?
I require to run a crate, that depends on the GDAL Rust crate, on a ZCU106 devkit. This requires me to cross-compile my code for the target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu. The crate compiles for the x86_64 architecture well, but on compiling for the given target, it cannot find the required header files and throws the error message:
wrapper.h:5:10: fatal error: 'cpl_atomic_ops.h' file not found
thread 'main' panicked at /home/arya/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/gdal-sys-0.9.1/build.rs:37:10:
Unable to generate bindings: ClangDiagnostic("wrapper.h:5:10: fatal error: 'cpl_atomic_ops.h' file not found\n")

I am using an Ubuntu 22.04 system. The contents of my .cargo/config file located inside the crate root are:
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker="aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc"

I have verified that the header files are indeed located inside of /usr/include/gdal, which leads me to think this is a path issue that might be fixed with specifying an appropriate environment variable. However, I'm not sure what to set.
Printing env didn't yield any relevant variables that I could set either.
I'm compiling this not as a standalone, but as a part of my Rust crate. Hence compiling the GDAL source alone will not work, it's being used in the crate through Rust wrappers. How do I fix this?

Set the GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR environment variable to /usr/include/gdal. This should make the build script look there.

Thank you, it got rid of that error at least. But now it's giving the error: The GDAL-SYS crate must emit the version of libgdal via cargo:version_number: NotPresent. Is there some similar environment variable like GDAL_VERSION or anything that I can set?

@arya-p Exactly this. Set GDAL_VERSION to the version (major.minor.patch).

Yes, that worked. Are these some standard GDAL environment variables? Where can I find a list?

If the OP is cross-compiling, then /usr/include/gdal is almost certainly the wrong place to look, since it will contain the headers for the host machine, instead of the target machine.
